# call method with param in an other method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn Vue.js and I have a problem.
How can I add the handler "addRowHandlers" in the function addUpHandler ?
I made a pagination system and when I turn the page 1, I lost my handler on the .
It's a basic system. I'm not making a new database request, I use a twig variable which contain all my datas

```
    addUpHandler: function(){
        //let up = document.getElementById('up');
        //let pageA = 1
        const text = document.getElementById('textSearchByName')
        if(text.value != ""){
            this.pageT += 1
            return searchByName(pageT)
        }
        let myTab = document.getElementById("myTab")
        myTab.innerHTML = ""
        this.pageA++;
        for(let i=(this.pageA-1)*10;i<this.pageA*10;i++){
            let dist = segments[i]['distance']/1000
            myTab.innerHTML += "<tr v-on:click='addRowHandlers($event)'><td>"+segments[i]['name']+"</td><td>"+segments[i]['nbSegment']+"</td><td>"+dist.toFixed(2)+"km</td><td>"+segments[i]['total_elevation_gain']+"m</td><td>"+segments[i]['average_grade']+"%</td><tr>"
        }
    },
    addRowHandlers: function(event){
        this.clearMap();
        var td = event.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName("td").length
        var cell = event.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; //get le premier td de la ligne
        var polyline = cell.firstElementChild.value;
        var idSeg = cell.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.value
        let distance = event.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
        distance = distance.firstElementChild.value
        this.getStreams(idSeg, distance, myChart)
        var coordonnee = L.Polyline.fromEncoded(polyline).getLatLngs();
                L.polyline(
                    coordonnee,
                    {
                        color: 'red',
                        weight: 2
                    }
                ).addTo(map)
    },
```

regards

PS: SOrry for my english

Comment: On clicking the tr you cant execute the function? If that is the case, try using this syntax for concatenating the strings ``string text ${expression} string text``. Following is the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Have you tried to preventDefault the event ?
`if (event) { event.preventDefault() }`

Comment: Hi @AdilRaza, On the first page it works, but not on the next....

Comment: Hi @nabais, where can I put this code ?

Comment: not sure if it will work, but before the `this.clearMap()`

Comment: @alex8276 Try this preventDefault method suggested by nabias. Put just after the function starts.

Comment: @nabais  It doesn't work

Comment: @alex8276 can you create a codepen link?

Comment: @AdilRaza https://codepen.io/alex8276/pen/abNPoXb. I don't know if it's clear. I try to "convert" a legacy js to vuejs so it's mixed...

Comment: It looks to me as generally bad practice to add HTML via DOM manipulation (innerHTML) through Vue functions. Vue is a reactive framework - the DOM is updated automatically based on your data. So you should probably have that for loop as a v-for in the template, and just change the underlying data in the functions.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasS, I going to try this. I must use an array and add my data inside for that v-for works ?

Comment: I don't understand how to do. When the page is loaded my data are display by twig variable. How to combine with vue ? How to get data sended by server ?

Comment: First, I wouldnt even use Twig as you already have Vue. But that is just my opinion. I havent used twig, but I guess it is similar to laravels blade. You could, for example, do something like this in your component: `data: function() {  twigData: {{ yourPHPVariable }}  },` and then access that data in your code with `this.twigData` or in your template with normal double curly braces

Comment: Also, you almost never need to use `document.getElementById` in Vue to access form inputs. Check out `v-model`, look up some example code etc. It looks like you are trying to migrate existing code into Vue.js, but using a reactive framework like vue has a totally different approach than using jQuery or vanilla JS. You dont need to manually get data from the dom or manipulate the dom, you just work directly with the data and let vue build the DOM. At first it is a new way of thinking, but once you get your head around it you will be amazed how great it is (and efficient)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @MatthiasS . I going to try this